# Honda Engine Seize & overheats

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle

I have `Honda Trigger CB` and it's a good motor vehicle but when I cross speed at 100km/hr. It heats a lot and often get seize in mid way. It then need to cool off to let me ride it again. Also it gives some sort of noises on crossing the speed of 95+ km/hr.

Any suggestions!

Comment: The engine actually seizes? As in goes solid? Then you let it cool and it will allow you to start it again? Or does it just quit running, you have to let it cool off, then it will start again? This is the [CB150](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_CB_Trigger), single cylinder, air cooled version, right? Please a little more detail to assist you.

Comment: Like Paulster2 points out, please elaborate `often get seize in mid way` in few more sentences. `Honda Trigger CB` is not a sport but street bike.

Comment: @Paulster2 Yes, you are right buddy. Please check the question. I edited it.

Comment: Please explain. A piston seize while traveling at 100kmph is absolutely dangerous, needless to say. Cooling off for a few minutes and you're fine to ride again? For how much time did you ride it above 100? A CB Trigger should not seize at such speeds if you rode it only for a little less than a few minutes. Are you sure it still has enough engine oil in it? Was the engine properly run-in? Are you sure the petrol was good (as in no kerosene in it)? Is the carb tuning proper? And like @SparKotॐ said, its not a street bike, but a commuter.

Comment: @You_Shall_Not_Pass. I use to ride it for 2 hours or more & yes, I do take care of proper amount of engine oil & good quality petrol before riding it.

Comment: Riding for more than 2 hours is certainly not a problem . Its a honda. :) Riding even an R15 for 2 hours at speeds above 100kmph will cause overheating even though its liquid cooled. Cb Trigger is a wonderful bike, but its not made to perform at such speed and certainly not for such long intervals (at such speeds). Ride Safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen similar symptoms with vehicles that have a semi-clogged fuel filter on gravity fed machines.  The blockage prevents full flow of the fuel.  The consumption of fuel driving at higher RPM's exceeds the fuel flow and the engine dies.  Once the fuel refills the carb float bowls the engine is able to start again.  Perhaps this is the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you're right. The engine dieing could be confused with the piston seizing. good thought.

Comment: Thanks, I hope it happens due to long riding at a good rpm and then the proper amount of oil it requires get less so it dies till it gets that amount back.